# excel lookup in multiple columns

Tags: excel, lookup

I have below 2 sheets.
Sheet 1

```
id review_name
1  Test1
2  Test2
3  Test3
```

Sheet 2

```
Review_name Date_range
Test1       B2:B248
Test2       AC2:A248
Test3       U2:U248
```

Here the Date_range refers to column names in sheet3.I should pick the review names and based on the above date_range(column range) of sheet 3,i should look for matching value.

Expected result

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
    1 test1 LOOKUP(1,Sheet3A2:A248,<Here i should use sheet2 lookup date_range>
```

Any suggestions, i used concatenate of sheet name and the range, like `LOOKUP(1,Sheet3A2:A248,Sheet3&B2:B248)` but dint work

Answer (score 0):

You'll need function `=INDIRECT()` to convert a string holding a sheet/range name into an actual range. Otherwise it just stays as a string which is meaningless. In your case something like:

```
=lookup(A1, Sheet3!A2:A248, indirect("Sheet3!" & vlookup(B1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, false)))
```

That last parameter of your `lookup` function is going to concatenate the string `Sheet3!` to the results of the vlookup, which will be the string range in Column B of Sheet2. That is then interpreted by `indirect()` into an actual range that will function in your `lookup()` formula.